# vscode & pipenv - pipenv not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip

I am consistently getting the following error with VSCode for Mac when using pipenv:

`Workspace contains Pipfile but 'pipenv' was not found. Make sure 'pipenv' is on the PATH.`

Running "which pipenv" gives a location (/usr/local/bin) that is in my PATH when I echo $PATH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue by providing an absolute path to my pipenv binary for the vscode setting `python.pipenvPath`. The default setting of "`pipenv`" does not appear to work, despite pipenv being part of my `PATH` and working just fine outside of vs code.

Comment: Setting `python.pipenvPath` in Workspace settings (not User settings) resolved this longstanding issue. Thanks!

Comment: I have defined this pipenvPath but vscode is still not able to detect it and keeps throwing the same message "Workspace contains Pipfile but 'pipenv' was not found. Make sure 'pipenv' is on the PATH."

Answer (score 0):

See that your python installation might be done in Appdata/Roaming folder instead of Local and PATH may be set for Appdata/Local folder. Correcting the PATH may correct the error.